# Check if character array contains different than allowed characters

Tags: c#, arrays, char, contains

My problem is this I have a character array of length 4 that basically represents a word (this array is a key in `dictionary<char[],int>`, that should not matter though).
I need to check if those words are comprised only from allowed characters, in this case {A, T, C, G}.

So all of the following words would be valid: AAAA, GGGG, GCGC, ATAT, ATGC, CCGA etc.

While following would not: AFGC, AAAS, TGCW etc.

I would like to avoid converting to string because of peformance.
My idea is something like this:

```
if (word.Contains(!'ACTG'))
```

Which shoudl represent: If (array word contains different characters than A and/or C and/or T and/or G=> return false).

Problem is I do not know how to write this syntax wise (if this is even possible to do in a way this simple).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ is great for this:

```
char[] allowed = { 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G' };
if (word.Any(c => !allowed.Contains(c)))
{
    // BZZZZTT! Bad character in word
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems like the solution I was looking for.